# Is it a bad idea to search for app config file up the dir structure?

Tags: php

I have a php app with a configuration file in its root. If I include it by it's absolute path, then I get a problem when I move the app elsewhere. If I include it by relative path, I get a problem when I move the file where the config is included. So, I've come up with something like this to search for the app config file down the directory structure.

```
$relative_path = "";
for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) {
    if (file_exists($relative_path."config.php")) {
        require ($relative_path."config.php");
        break;
    } 
    $relative_path .= "../";
}
```

Could this be a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

It would add some security risk. - If someone manages to place a config file "on top" you script would find this first and include / execute it... (This could range from config manipulation to some serious attack...)

Comment: For this to happen someone would have to get writable access to my webserver's directory structure which would be a disaster on its own, wouldn't it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Misconfigured file uploads for the most simple example

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use `dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/config.php';`

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__) == __DIR`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use the server globals? For instance:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../config.php');
```

Comment: In this case I'd have to modify the code every time I have to move the file up/down in the directory structure.

Comment: True, unless you define it into a variable in your bootstrap file, and then just refering to it in all of your dependent files.